# change labels in a list

Tags: r, list

I created a list:

```
aka3 = list(ID = c(AAtr="white", Anox24h="ivory4", Anox48h="goldenrod3", Anox24hATF='red'))
```

I am trying to change label the ID:

```
aka3$ID<- c( labels=c(AAtr="AA tr", Anox24h="Anox 24h", Anox48h="Anox48h", Anox24hATF="Anox 24h ATF"))
```

Labels could be changed when list is created or after, either way would be OK.

Comment: maybe you want `names(aka3$ID) <- c(AAtr="AA tr", Anox24h="Anox 24h", Anox48h="Anox48h", Anox24hATF="Anox 24h ATF")`. Its kind of hard to tell.

Comment: True, how can this be done when I create the list?

Comment: What about `aka3 <- list(ID = c(AAtr="AA tr", Anox24h="Anox 24h", Anox48h="Anox48h", Anox24hATF="Anox 24h ATF"))`?

Comment: I create a colour map list (check the first line of my script), but I need also to rename the IDs of my colour map. With: `aka3 <- list(ID = c(AAtr="AA tr", Anox24h="Anox 24h", Anox48h="Anox48h", Anox24hATF="Anox 24h ATF"))` I loose color info. Is it possible to change the names while I create the list? Thanks

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do, but you can also use the names directly, if that is helpful: `myLabels <- names(aka3$ID)` or you could add this to your existing list. `ada3$labels <- names(aka3$ID)`. Neither of these are really necessary, as should be able to use these names directly via `names(aka3$ID)` in whatever you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to create the list with the right labels:

```
aka3 = list(ID = c("AA tr"="white", "Anox 24h"="ivory4", "Anox 48h"="goldenrod3", 
"Anox 24h ATF"='red'))

> aka3
$ID
       AA tr     Anox 24h     Anox 48h Anox 24h ATF 
     "white"     "ivory4" "goldenrod3"        "red"
```